# GKE Cronjob RAM Disparity vs Local

Tags: pandas, google-kubernetes-engine

Hello I am new to using GKE and am running into an issue with a computationally heavy task. When I run the task locally with the exact same script and same amount of data it never crashes. I am running this on a computer with 8 gb of RAM.

When I run this on a GKE pod with 20 gb of RAM allocated, it routinely crashes. I want to understand what is going on here?

The flow is as such:

pull data from warehouse
load to pandas dataframe
perform computation
load to warehouse

I have tried upping the resource limits on GKE. I have implemented limits (that are above the requrested resources). I am not sure what else to check.